# How to upgrade older python 2.7.x version to 2.7.16?

Tags: python, python-2.7, upgrade

One of my machines has a python version 2.7.13. I want to upgrade this to v2.7.16 How can I do that? What other things (e.g. obsolete packages or modules) might I have to consider while doing this?

Comment: A straightforward install should do it. That will overwrite 2.7.13, which is generally not a problem for patch level upgrades (what PEP 440 calls *micro* version numbers). And it would be most unusual for an imported package to have a dependency on a patch level.

Comment: @BoarGules straightforward meaning from the installer released on python website right?

Comment: I would not dream of doing it any other way.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use anaconda and create environment with python version 2.7.16

```
conda create --name py27 python==2.7.16
```